# Java methods that get to wait somehow and that throw InterruptedException

Tags: java, interrupt

I'm looking for a list of methods that throw an `InterruptedException`. So far, I've got `sleep()` & `join()` of `Thread` and `wait()` of `Object`. 
Are there any others anywhere in Java that throw an `InterruptedException` or this is it?

Note: I'm not asking anything else about Java interrupts. just looking to get the comprehensive list.

//=====================================

EDIT: rephrasing the Q for a bit more:

*"the methods that throw an `InterruptedException` in Java are those invoking `wait()`, `join()` and `sleep()` of `Object` and `Thread`. These 3 methods are the "roots" of Java interrupts."*

is this statement true?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/class-use/InterruptedException.html

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth : Quite interesting, that deserves a proper answer. Please post it.

Comment: @Roam You haven't yet accepted Oliver's answer. Please accept it.

Comment: I see that you've edited the question to ask about the "roots" of interrupts. I've edited my answer to include a list of classes that generate one from scratch.

Comment: @Roam You asked Oliver to answer so you can accept it, and Oliver put it in answer. But yet you haven't accepted his answer. It's complete waste of effort for Oliver. Do you know how he may be feeling?

Comment: @Meraman That was only half an hour ago. I'm sure Oliver is man enough to wait for his sweeties, and doesn't need you to get upset on his behalf.

Comment: @chiastic-security I apologize if I underestimated your answer, but I haven't. +1ed it. Your effort is really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your second question about the *roots* of the `InterruptedException`s, the following classes actually *generate* one (i.e., `throw new InterruptedException(...);`). This is from my JDK (OpenJDK 1.8.0.11).

For clarity, these are all the outer classes (i.e., not inner classes) that throw a new `InterruptedException` somewhere, including in an inner class. In other words, if class `X` has an inner class `X.Y`, and `X.Y` has a method that throws a new `InterruptedException`, then it will appear in this list as `X`. It does *not* include *native* methods that generate one (which is why `java.lang.Object` doesn't appear here). The only two classes with *native* methods that throw an `InterruptedException` are `java.lang.Object` and `java.lang.Thread`.

```
java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier
java.util.concurrent.LinkedTransferQueue
java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool
java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedLongSynchronizer
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer
java.util.concurrent.locks.StampedLock
java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue
java.util.concurrent.Phaser
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
java.util.concurrent.Exchanger
java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask
java.lang.InterruptedException
com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.concurrent.DebugMutex
com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.concurrent.Mutex
com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.concurrent.CondVar
com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.concurrent.ReentrantMutex
com.sun.jmx.snmp.daemon.SnmpAdaptorServer
com.sun.jmx.snmp.daemon.CommunicatorServer
```

Here's the complete list of classes from my JDK that can throw one, including one that's generated at a lower level in the stack.

```
javax.swing.SwingWorker
javax.swing.SwingUtilities
java.nio.file.WatchService
java.nio.channels.AsynchronousChannelGroup
java.awt.MediaTracker
java.awt.image.PixelGrabber
java.awt.EventQueue
java.util.concurrent.Executors
java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier
java.util.concurrent.LinkedTransferQueue
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
java.util.concurrent.DelayQueue
java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch
java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService
java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor
java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture
java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService
java.util.concurrent.CompletionService
java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedLongSynchronizer
java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer
java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition
java.util.concurrent.locks.StampedLock
java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock
java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue
java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue
java.util.concurrent.TransferQueue
java.util.concurrent.Semaphore
java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue
java.util.concurrent.Phaser
java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
java.util.concurrent.BlockingDeque
java.util.concurrent.Future
java.util.concurrent.Exchanger
java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask
java.lang.UNIXProcess
java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue
java.lang.Process
java.lang.Object
java.lang.Thread
sun.font.CreatedFontTracker
sun.nio.fs.AbstractWatchService
sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl
sun.nio.ch.PendingFuture
sun.misc.Lock
sun.misc.ConditionLock
sun.misc.Queue
sun.misc.VM
sun.toolsc.SourceClass
sun.awt.X11.XBaseWindow
sun.awt.X11.XSelection
sun.awt.EventQueueDelegate
sun.awt.SunToolkit
sun.awt.im.ExecutableInputMethodManager
sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder
sun.awt.AWTAccessor
sun.applet.AppletPanel
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.ImageDataContentHandler
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ImageDataContentHandler
com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.concurrent.DebugMutex
com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.concurrent.Sync
com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.concurrent.Mutex
com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.concurrent.CondVar
com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.concurrent.ReentrantMutex
com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.threadpool.WorkQueueImpl
com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.ThreadControllerWrapper
com.sun.tools.sjavac.server.CompilerPool
com.sun.tools.example.debug.bdi.JDIEventSource
com.sun.tools.example.debug.bdi.ExecutionManager
com.sun.tools.example.debug.bdi.ThreadInfo
com.sun.tools.example.debug.gui.ContextManager
com.sun.tools.jdi.EventQueueImpl
com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ArrayNotificationBuffer
com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.NotificationBuffer
com.sun.jmx.snmp.daemon.SnmpAdaptorServer
com.sun.jmx.snmp.daemon.CommunicatorServer
com.sun.jndi.ldap.EventQueue
com.sun.jdi.event.EventQueue
com.sun.swing.SwingUtilities3
```

Comment: I believe there would also be a number of native methods that cause/throw InterruptedException.... Thread.join, for example.

Comment: @rolfl Yes, I've added this in now. Only `java.lang.Thread` and `java.lang.Object` have native methods that throw an `InterruptedException`.

Answer (score 4):

Comprehensive list available via JavaDoc:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/class-use/InterruptedException.html.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that there is a comprehensive list, but your current list is far from complete.

Many of the methods in `java.util.concurrent.*` throw the exception. Just look at [`Future` which has a couple](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) and others in that package.

Then there are the NIO function calls, channels, etc. There's lots (thousands).